# 7zip on windows 11 create zip file with password

Tags: windows, 7-zip

i'm using the following command from command line

```
.\7za.exe a  "C:\TMP\updates.7z" "C:\test\Output\TMP\*" -t7z -ptest
```

The file was correctly created, but with no password protection. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://info.nrao.edu/computing/guide/file-access-and-archiving/7zip/7z-7za-command-line-guide

Comment: Have you try command like: `.\7za.exe a -t7z -ptest  "C:\TMP\updates.7z" "C:\test\Output\TMP\*`

Comment: I used that guide and i tried to move the -p switch in every position.

Comment: Are you sure there is actually no password protection, can you open/extract the files without password, or maybe you can simply see the filenames? If you add `-mhe` that will also encrypt/protect the filenames, so it will ask for a password right when opening the 7z file.

Comment: It should work (and works for me on Windows 11) regardless where the switches are

Comment: There might be a difference between opening the archive and extracting the files, regarding password usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 7Zip archive created with a password using the command in the
post can be opened without asking for the password.

The password is only required when accessing the files that are
included in the locked archive.

To prevent the archive from opening at all, add for a better
encryption the parameter `-mhe=on`, described as :

> 7z format only : enables or disables archive header encryption (Default : off)

Comment: To note that depends on whether the folder/filenames are also encrypted or not. This is an optional setting when creating the archive

Comment: @YisroelTech: Right, I added it.